# jstree 3.0.0 stuck on loading json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

I am creating tree navigation with jstree.

It works if I use static data either defined in HTML or assigned to `jstree.core.data`, however when I specify `jstree.core.data.url` it does not. Just shows loading forever.

Does not matter if I specify static json file or ajax url as source.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.treeview.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="stuck"></div>
<br/>
<div id="stuck2"></div>
<br/>
<div id="works"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jstree.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#stuck').jstree({
    "core" : {
    'data': {
        'url' : 'catalog.json'
        }
  },
});
$('#stuck2').jstree({
'core' : {
  'data' : {
    'url' : function (node) {
      return node.id === '#' ? 
        'ajax_roots.json' : 
        'ajax_children.json';
    },
    'data' : function (node) {
      return { 'id' : node.id };
    }
  }
 }
});
$('#works').jstree({ 'core' : {
    'data' : [
       { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Simple root node" },
       { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2" },
       { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 1" },
       { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" },
    ]
} });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have:

- Tested JSON with [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/).
- Used same JSON for working and not working cases
- Changed response headers to `application/json` or `text/json` both in `php` and/or `nginx`
- Multiple browsers
- Tried 1.9.0. and 1.11.0 versions of jQuery.
- Looked through similar questions on SO, but those are about older jstree.
- Tried running docs/index.html from jstree. Same problem.

How can I debug this? I get no errors or warnings in console.

Comment: Your URL must point to the host where your script is served from. This is a security requirement, see  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy. Search for cross domain. There are exceptions, but they require special server headers.

Comment: Use the network tab of a JavaScript console of your browser to check the network interaction. Learning to use a JavaScript debugger helps to trace such problems.

Comment: @liepumartins, I had this problem a few hours ago, but it was solved when i passed back the correct JSON content type BACK to the client, specifically : Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have made numerous errors:

1. Apparently I did not check all of JSON files, some had key names without quotes or with single quotes instead of double.
2. When passign JSON data inline, like specified in 3rd example. It works also without key names in quotes, so invalid JSON worked inline, but not when getting it via `XHR`. Confusing.
3. The example from docs/index.html did not work because of security measures mentioned by mvw. The error message is:

   `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`